# How to change layout of Office's Fabric elements?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm fairly new to React and Microsoft's Fabric. I've been trying to figure out if I can change the layout of elements inside a `<GroupHeader>`
Looking at the [source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/GroupedList/GroupHeader.base.tsx) it's not totally clear to me if the elements follow some sort of layout style, or if they just appear in the order of declaration inside the render function. I was hoping to rearrange some elements rather than create a completely custom `<GroupHeader>`. I've tried adjusting some CSS properties and passing those in as a `className`, but it hasn't worked.

Is there a way to do that? Or what would be the best approach to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put this [codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/KLMKxb) real quick to show how a GroupHeader can be styled by changing the order of the collapse button. There are probably a few other methods including a regular css style or even a custom `onRenderHeader` but it looks like you don't wanna create a custom renderer. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yes! Just what I needed. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible to replace the checkbox like this? I want to use the square checkbox rather than the circle one. I see `check` is part of `IGroupHeaderStyles` as well, but I'm not totally sure how I can specify a different asset to be used. Or do I have to do it via `onRenderHeader` function?

Comment: Yes... I believe for `check` you will be needing to override the entire header with the help of `onRenderHeader`. It could be also reached with some deep styling selectors top change the shape of the round `check` to a square one but I believe at this point an entire override is more suitable depending on how customized is your design. Also, you might consider filing an issue on Github by requesting a feature to easier replace the render of the check. Keep in mind that when overriding there is always a risk to loose some of the accessibility of DOM elements we have built in in the default one.